# Can I multiply the Pearson Coefficients by 10 to make impact?

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, pearson-r

I have extracted the Pearson correlation Coefficients between the labels and features. Can I multiply the final correlation score for each score by 10 to make it higher to investigate it with machine learning?

Comment: (1) What do you hope to achieve by the rescaling? (2) Why are you interested in the *correlation* between the labels and the features? Why don't you directly model the labels, with the features as predictors?

Comment: By labels do you mean a categorical variable?

Comment: @StephanKolassa I hope to achieve a clearer relation between the labels and features. currently the correlation is between 0.02 and 0.03 and I want to create a prediction model out of them.  Will I get the same prediction results if I used 0.02 and 0.2 (in random forest)?

Comment: @user2974951 Continuous variables

Comment: I've posted an answer, though I am not at all clear what you want to do with these numbers. It might be best to say what you're trying to do.

Comment: Are you trying to change a correlation or just how you represent the correlation?

Comment: @Glen_b for now I am only using the multiplication to represent the correlation. If I change the actual correlation, will it have different impact on my ML model?

Comment: It would depend on how you're achieving that, but if that's not what you're doing we should probably leave that aside.

Comment: The correlation is whatever it is. You don’t get to pick it any more than you get to pick how tall you are or how fast you can run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SURE**

That's a conversion of units, analogous to expressing in decimeters instead of meters.

However, I have my doubts that this would make a difference. When it might matter is if you need to present to an audience that would rather see percentages (so multiplying by $100\%$, not just $10$) than decimal numbers less than $1$ (e.g., $26\%$ instead of $0.26$).